# Lubuntu 12.04 on powerbook g4 "Wireless Networks device not found (firmware missing)"

Tags: 12.04, wireless, lubuntu, powerpc

I installed Lubuntu 12.04 on my powerbook g4 but when I try to connect to WiFi it says "Wireless Networks device not found (firmware missing)" How do I fix this? I am new to Lubuntu (and terminal).  I typed

```
lspci -nn | grep 0280
```

into terminal.  And got out

```
0001:10:12.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4306 802.11b/g Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4320] (rev 02)
```

and the 0280 was red

After typing in

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43legacy-installer
```

while attached to the Ethernet, I got out

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done E: Unable to locate package firmware-b43legacy-intaller
```

I rebooted my computer and nothing changed

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal command: lspci -nn | grep 0280  Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry I am very inexperienced with terminal but I typed that in and got    0001:10:12.0 Network controller [0280]:  Broadcom Corporation BCM4306 802.11b/g Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4320] (rev 02)                and the 0280 was red

Comment: You did a perfect job! No worries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please walk the computer over to the router to get a temporary wired ethernet connection. Open the terminal again and copy and paste this into the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43legacy-installer
```

Press Enter. After it's done, detach the ethernet, reboot and give us your report.

Comment: I typed that in and got out  'Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done E: Unable to locate package firmware-b43legacy-intaller'

Comment: Please see my edit.